# How do I update my in-app-purchase app

Tags: in-app-purchase

I have the app in apple store with in app purchase.  Now I need to update the app with some improvements.   I have a question about the customers who already purchased the full feature from in app purchase and how do they get the new updates?  I am new to in app purchase.  Thanks for your help and answer!

Emmy

Comment: Is this question programming-related ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user already bought one of the in-app purchase products, those products will still be downloaded after the user updates to the latest version of the app.

If a user un-installs or installs on a new device, the products they purchased in the past can be re-downloaded without having to re-purchase.

I'd suggest using a service like Urban Airship to make the in-app purchase process simple.  They've got a great SDK for IAP.